# Follow-up question to my previous question

Tags: python, oop

Previously, I have asked for help on  a school project due in a few days, it's a digit span test in python that requires the implementation of Object Orient Programming. I have further improved on my code, here it is currently:

```
import time
import random
import os

appeartimeframe = float(1)
os.system('cls')
print("Welcome to the digit span test.")
time.sleep(1)
os.system('cls')
time.sleep(1)
print("We hope you enjoy.")
time.sleep(1)
os.system('cls')

randomlist = []
def start():
    game_state = 0
    a = 5
    index = 1
    while game_state == 0:
        for i in range(0,a):
            n = random.randint(1,9)
            randomlist.append(n)

        time.sleep(1)
        os.system('cls')
        print('Get ready.')
        arr = []
        for i in range(0, len(randomlist)):
            time.sleep(1)    
            print(randomlist[i])
            time.sleep(appeartimeframe)
            os.system('cls')    

        for i in range(0, a):
            answer = int(input("enter answer "))
            arr.append(answer)

        if arr == randomlist:
            print("nice")
        else: 
            print("uh oh")
            

def main():
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        gamediff = int(input("Input Difficulty ( 1 - 4 ):  "))
        if gamediff == 1:
            print("Difficulty [ EASY ] selected.")
            appeartimeframe == 2
            start()
        elif gamediff == 2:
            print("Difficulty [ MEDIUM ] selected.")
            appeartimeframe == 1.6
            start()
        elif gamediff == 3:
            print("Difficulty [ HARD ] selected.")
            appeartimeframe == 1.2
            start()
        elif gamediff == 4:
            print("Difficulty [ VIRTUALLY IMPOSSIBLE ] selected.")
            appeartimeframe == 0.7
            start()
        else:
            print("Invalid Difficulty selected.")
            return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Here are a few persisting problems and a few new ones that I have yet to solve and require help on:

1. The array 'randomlist' adds 5 numbers every time I remember the sequence.
2. No idea on how to implement OOP
3. No idea on how to implement a 'lose' state ( perhaps it's related to OOP, I have no clue. )

Answer (score 0):

1. after you call `randomlist = []` you never reset the content of the list. After your player won or lost you should reset the list (e.g before you fill it with random numbers again)
2. Do some reading on main OOP Concepts like classes and methods and how they are implemented in python.

https://realpython.com/python3-object-oriented-programming/

You could do a class `Game` which manages the game objects (randomlist,..) and the state (eg .playing, won, lost)

3. Well you have a loop checking for an `gamestate == 0`. A lose state could be used to determine if the current player remembered correctly.

Comment: Would you care to elaborate please? I'm completely lost.